# Passing a variable in string in Embedded C

Tags: c, gcc, microcontroller, avr-gcc, atmelstudio

I am using ATmega8 and I am trying to send string over USART (in `printf` style) which include a variable .I am using `Atmel Studio 6.2` as IDE for AVR programming. Here is my code:-

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void USARTInit(uint16_t ubrr_value)  // initialize USART
{

    UBRRL = ubrr_value;
    UBRRH = (ubrr_value>>8);
    UCSRC|=(1<<URSEL)|(1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<UCSZ0);
    UCSRB=(1<<RXCIE)|(1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);

}

void USARTWriteChar(char data) // send character using USART
{

    while(!(UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)));
    UDR=data;
}

void send_string(char s[])   // send string using USART
{
    int i =0;

    while (s[i] != 0x00)
    {
        USARTWriteChar(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    USARTWriteChar('\n');
}


int main(void)
{
    USARTInit(51);
    char val='A';
    while(1)
    {
        send_string("Value = %c",val);

    }
}
```

Now when I compile my code I got this error:-

> too many arguments to function 'send_string`

So, clearly it is not accepting `%c` as it does in C programming. Is there a way in `embedded C` to pass a variable in a string?

Comment: There is no language "embedded C"! And that function is not part of the standard library, so, it does **not** work in "C programming". You might first want to learn C and what functions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *too many arguments to function `send_string`*

The message is quite clear there, your `send_string()` accepts only a pointer to `char` as input argument, but while calling, you're trying to pass two input arguments `"Value = %c",val` causing the mis-match.

You cannot use format specifiers here the way you have shown.

In general, the way to go is to use a temporary buffer, use [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to generate the input string and then, pass the buffer to the `send_string()` call.

That said, since you're only *interested* in passing the value of `c` to `send_string()`, you can reduce the function to take only a `char`, like

```
void send_string(char s) { ...
```

and then, pass the constant (*pre-defined*) string `Value =` and then, the input argument go get the same effect.

Comment: You actually *can* - But you need to re-write the function to take a variable argument list. Your method using `s[n]printf`is much less effort, however.

Comment: Sorry, but using the `printf`-bloat on an embedded system is a really bad idea - if it is available at all.

Comment: @tofro that's why I mentioned _"..the way you have shown.."_.

Comment: @Olaf ok, in that regards, I've added an alternate approach.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, there is no such thing as embedded C language. You are programming in C. And this code is invalid.

Your function void `send_string(char s[])` accepts only one argument of type `char []`. You are calling it as `send_string("Value = %c",val);`, so you are passing two arguments to it. In C strings `%` character doesn't have special meaning. It is only meaningfull to `printf` functions. You call is equivalent to `send_string("It doesn't matter what you write here", 'A');`

You can do what you wanted in another way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
int main(void)
{
    USARTInit(51);
    char val='A';
    char buffer[64];
    sprintf(buffer, "Value = %c", val);
    while(1)
    {
        send_string(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I repeat what I wrote to the other answer: Using the `printf`-bloat on an embedded system is a really bad idea - if it is available at all. (And your answer contains the same as the other, just a bit more elaborate). Btw. 1KiB buffer on a system which has just 1KiB of RAM?? Seriously?

Comment: @Olaf It's should be that bad as long as you don't call it too often. For me it was working quite well on STM32. On Atmega8 it must be worse though... And yes, probably 1KiB buffer on Atmega8 is not that good idea... Anyway we don't know what OP is trying to achieve but clearly he wanted to use `printf` syntax. I don't recommend it either.

Comment: @Olaf I mean that if the operation takes 1 second, but it is executed once a minute, then its execution time can be acceptable. I simply answered the question. He wanted to use `printf` syntax. Write a better answer if you wish, but clearly OP isn't experienced programmer and wanted something simple... What is slow and what isn't depends on your requirements. Sometimes you want to implement a feature quickly, without reinventing float to string conversion and stuff like that.

Comment: You did not answer the question, as you don't take the implicit constraints into account. The `embedded` tag exists for a reason. And no, OP did not want to use "`printf` syntax", but output an additional char. The format-string is just how he tried it. From the question alone one can judge that OP lacks the basics and just copies a pattern, but without knowing what it means (fact, no offence!).